# jQuery - Deferreds waiting for an array of ajax requests to complete even failures

Tags: jquery-deferred, deferred, deferred-execution

How can execute a function after a number of ajax requests have all completed regardless of whether they succeeded or error-ed out?

I've been trying to use `$.when.apply(this, array)` to pass an array of deferred jqXHR objects. However just like the docs say

> In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when immediately >fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred. Note that some of the Deferreds may still be >unresolved at that point.

How can leverage jQuery deferred objects to always wait for all the ajax calls to finish?

Maybe I should create my own deferred that will wrap all the other deferreds? If so I'm not quite clear how to set that up.

Comment: looks like [this is the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5825233/99985) i was looking for. you have to wrap each ajax call in a deferred that gets resolved via the complete function. then pass the whole array into when().

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of how the Promise specification is likely going for the future with a `PromiseInspection` object, here's a jQuery add-on function that tells you when all promises are done, whether fulfilled or rejected:

```js
(function() {    
    // pass either multiple promises as separate arguments or an array of promises
    $.settle = function(p1) {
        var args;
        if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
              args = p1;
        } else {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        }

        return $.when.apply($, args.map(function(p) {
            // make sure p is a promise (it could be just a value)
            p = wrapInPromise(p);
            // Make sure that the returned promise here is always resolved with a PromiseInspection object, never rejected
            return p.then(function(val) {
                return new PromiseInspection(true, val);
            }, function(reason) {
                // Convert rejected promise into resolved promise by returning a resolved promised
                // One could just return the promiseInspection object directly if jQuery was
                // Promise spec compliant, but jQuery 1.x and 2.x are not so we have to take this extra step
                return wrapInPromise(new PromiseInspection(false, reason));
            });
        })).then(function() {
              // return an array of results which is just more convenient to work with
              // than the separate arguments that $.when() would normally return
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        });
    }

    // utility functions and objects
    function isPromise(p) {
        return p && (typeof p === "object" || typeof p === "function") && typeof p.then === "function";
    }

    function wrapInPromise(p) {
        if (!isPromise(p)) {
            p = $.Deferred().resolve(p);
        }
        return p;
    }

    function PromiseInspection(fulfilled, val) {
        return {
            isFulfilled: function() {
                return fulfilled;
            }, isRejected: function() {
                return !fulfilled;
            }, isPending: function() {
                // PromiseInspection objects created here are never pending
                return false;
            }, value: function() {
                if (!fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .value() on a promise that is not fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }, reason: function() {
                if (fulfilled) {
                    throw new Error("Can't call .reason() on a promise that is fulfilled");
                }
                return val;
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
$.settle(promiseArray).then(function(inspectionArray) {
    inspectionArray.forEach(function(pi) {
        if (pi.isFulfilled()) {
            // pi.value() is the value of the fulfilled promise
        } else {
            // pi.reason() is the reason for the rejection
        }
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that `$.settle()` will always fulfill (never reject) and the fulfilled value is an array of `PromiseInspection` objects and you can interrogate each one to see if it was fulfilled or rejected and then fetch the corresponding value or reason.  See the demo below for example usage:

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y0gjs31r/

Comment: Would `return $.when(p).then(...);` not avoid the need for all that type testing?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Probably, but I was specifically trying to avoid wrapping in yet another promise when that isn't needed.  So, I'm testing for the case of when it's already a promise and thus does not need to be wrapped again.  I could probably put that type testing off in a utility function call `isPromise()` and it would look cleaner.

Comment: Are you aware that [$.when(p) returns p if p is a promise](https://jsfiddle.net/pdjhhqo3/)?

Comment: You are right, it's a special case but one you can rely on here because the outer `$.when()` would ensure an inner `$.when()` would see only settled promises.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - I could certainly replace `p = $.Deferred().resolve(p);` with `p = $.when(p);` as a coding shortcut, but I don't understand what else you are suggesting?  When the `.map()` function is running, these are usually unsettled promises at that point (unless a settled promise was passed to `$.settle()` which isn't the normal design case).

Comment: Dang, the. map() executes first! I thought I spotted an efficient way to allow you to avoid the ugly type testing but I think you're stuck with it.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - You have given me a couple ideas for code cleanup.  I'll add those.