# Wait until everything executes even failures using $.when()

Tags: jquery, wait, jquery-deferred

With `jQuery.when()`, if one request fails then they all fail.

```
$.when(deferred1, deferred2).then(function() {
    // Called only after both deferred are resolved
}, function() {
    // Called immediately after one of the deferreds is rejected
});
```

How can you wait for everything to execute even failures? I tried to use `.always()` instead of `.then()` but the callback is also being called right after the first failure.

One (ugly) solution would be to have flags to control when both operations are completed and use the `.always()` on each of them (without `$.when()`).

```
var deferred1Complete = false;
var deferred2Complete = false;

function callback() {
    if (deferred1Complete && deferred2Complete) {
        // Execute after both deferred are either resolved or rejected
    }
}

deferred1.always(function() {
    deferred1Complete = true;
    callback();
});

deferred2.always(function() {
    deferred2Complete = true;
    callback();
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I found other interesting solutions in this questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152595/jquery-deferreds-waiting-for-an-array-of-ajax-requests-to-complete-even-failur) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824615/jquery-when-callback-for-when-all-deferreds-are-no-long-unresolved-either-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonatan,

I like your solution and offer a few improvements to :

- phrase as jQuery utility method, like [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)
- allow individual promises or an array of promises to be passed in
- resolve immediately if no arguments or an empty array is passed in
- be tolerant of non-promises/non-deferreds
- allow progress of the chain to be reported as each promise is resolved or rejected.

Here's the code :

```
(function($) {
    $.whenAlways = function(chain) {
        if(!chain || !$.isArray(chain)) chain = $.extend([], arguments);
        var n = chain.length;
        return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
            $.each(chain, function(i, promise) {
                if(!promise.always) n--;
                else {
                    promise.always(function() {
                        deferred.notify(--n);
                        if(n == 0) deferred.resolve();
                    });
                }
            });
            if(n == 0) deferred.resolve();
        }).promise();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

This approach would allow any progressCallbacks (added to the retuned promise) to be called whenever a `chain` promise is reolved/rejected, regardless of reolution/rejection order. By passing the number of outstanding `chain` promises to the progressCallbacks, you could, for example, provide a countdown indication or respond to intermediate countdown milestones.

Seems to work - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbHqr/)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (not so ugly) would be to chain the deferreds `.always()` callbacks.

```
deferred1.always(function() {
    deferred2.always(function() {
        // Execute after both deferred are either resolved or rejected
    });
});
```

I wrote a small function to handle this:

```
function whenAlways() {
    var chain = $.extend([], arguments);
    return new $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        var callback = function() {
            if (chain.length == 0) {
                deferred.resolve();
                return;
            }
            var object = chain.shift();
            $.when(object).always(callback);
        };
        callback();
    }).promise();
}
```

Usage:

```
whenAlways(deferred1, deferred2)
    .done(function() {
        // Execute after both deferred are either resolved or rejected
    });
```