# Equivalent of jQuery.when that allows for failures

Tags: jquery, ajax

I found out that my multiple requests work appropriately when they all succeed, but if one of them fails for whatever reason, my callback is not executed. I dug in the jQuery documentation, that says

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to
>   jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master"
>   Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds
>   it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as
>   soon as all the Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as
>   soon as one of the Deferreds is rejected

Which means that if I submit `n` requests and they all succeed, the master object will trigger a success resolution, and the connected callback (with `.then` or `.done`) will fire. However, if any of those `n` requests fail, the master Promise will be rejected and I will get a failCallback called when the other subpromises are potentially still working. Additionally, I won't have access to those subpromises in the callback unless I play with closures.

What is the correct way of submitting multiple ajax requests in jQuery and have the same behavior regardless if any of them fail?

Comment: Note, might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824615/jquery-when-callback-for-when-all-deferreds-are-no-longer-unresolved-either?rq=1, but it was 5 years ago, so maybe there's something for that today.

Comment: if you don't mind if you got success or failure, why not use the always() object ?

Comment: @polisha989 because always triggers regardless of the resolution status of the master deferred, but that does _not_ mean that when the master object is marked resolved (due to a failure) all other subdeferreds are done.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to return success regardless if an individual request fails (assuming too that you would handle this separately) So, a quick suggestion, and forgive me if you've already considered this, is to wrap your AJAX calls in try {} catch {} blocks, to prevent terminal failure within the when() like:

```
    var ajax1 = function () { //do ajax stuff but return "success" on err
    var ajax2 = function () { //do ajax stuff but return "success" on err 
    
    $.when(ajax1, ajax2).then(doMoreStuff);
```

and in the ajax functions add something like:

```
    var ajax1 = function () {
        try {
            $.ajax(function () { 
                success: function(res){ //do stuff}
            });
        } catch () {
            //do nothing, I believe this will return an ok
        }
    }
```

Or, a different approach:

```
$.ajax(function () { 
    success: function(){}, 
    error: function () {
        //handle the error 
        return success; 
});
```

This is almost pseudo code to demonstrate the concept, assuming you can fill in the blanks.

Hope it helps!

### Update

In response to your comment.  I was thinking something like:

```
var promise1 = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax ({
        success: function () { 
            //do stuff
            resolve("success");
       },
        error: function () { 
            //address your issue
            resolve("success");
    });
});

$.when(promise1, promise2, ...);
```

I've added a try catch to the original example.

Comment: so basically neutralise the problem, but my deferreds are the ajax promises. I can't try catch the request code, but I can certainly wrap them

Answer (score 0):

I didn't suggest this at first, because it seems that you are working with promises/deferreds that you could list separately, but using $.apply() may work instead.  This will run all items in an array "individually".

```
var promiseArray = [ajax1, ajax2, ...];
$.when.apply($, promiseArray).then(function() { //do the final stuff }
```

That should run all of them and run .then() even if you have a problem with one.

Comment: Nope. If you do apply on an array, it creates a master deferred that `.resolve` when all are resolved, but `.rejects` when any one is rejected. Given that the ajax objects are Deferred-like, when one fails, the master object is rejected, and your then function will not run.